# How to access docker mediawiki from another machine on the network?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, mediawiki

I'm a complete newcomer to docker (and also a Linux novice). I've just installed docker and mediawiki on a Lubuntu 16.10 VM running on an ESXi 6.5 host. I followed guidance here

```
https://github.com/addshore/mediawiki-docker-dev
```

I have mediawiki up and running on the Lubuntu VM, and can access it using:

```
http://default.web.mw.localhost:8080
```

I'd like to access mediawiki from another machine on the LAN, but don't know where to start. I've tried this command:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 apache
```

but got this error:

```
Unable to find image 'apache:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for apache, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
```

Is there a simple way of getting access to my docker/mediawiki site from another machine?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says... `apache` is not an image name

MediaWiki has an official docker image... And you should not use sudo to run containers

```
docker run --name some-mediawiki -p 8080:80 -d mediawiki
```